# select a 'virtual' column computed from other existing columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is it possible in sql/sqlite3 to perform a select where the column doesnt exist but is the computed result of other columns?

e.g. Given a table with columns max and current, I would like to perform a select on the diffrence of between the two so if I had:

```
table_data:
max|current
10|3
12|8

select ???? from table_data order by ????? asc;

desired result:
4
7
```

sqlite3 grammar here http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html but cant make sense of it

Comment: I would ask how to append such virtual column to SELECT *. Wow `SELECT *, '1' as "im"` works!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select `max` - `current` as `result` from table_data order by `result` asc
```

Comment: thanks. will prob use OMG Ponies cleaner syntax but this i was able try out with copy paste

Answer (score 2):

If this isn't just a one-off, you're probably better off with a view.

```
create view yourtable_diffs as 
select max, current, max - current as diff from yourtable;
```

Then you can just

```
 select diff from yourtable_diffs order by diff;
```

You might take a look at the [SQL tutorial](http://www.firstsql.com/tutor1.htm) from FirstSQL J.

Comment: this looks good. so yourtable_diffs will persist and the values calculated automatically? the benefit is what, cleaner query? what if i wanted to select columns from a combination of yourtable_diffs and table_data?

Comment: Yes, views persist. Calculations are done automatically. The benefits are that the calculation is written once, proven correct (to the satisfaction of the developer), and made available to everyone who needs it. That's more reliable that rewriting the calculation every time its needed. (Not a lot of benefit here, because the calculation is so simple, but calculations can be arbitrarily complex, involving many tables.) You can select columns from tables and views at the same time. See my edit above.